# What is the command to delete release bundle v2 by version value

Tags: jfrog-cli

I created a release bundle v2, but realized i can't update it from commands, so I just want to delete it and re-upload it. Is it possible, if yes, what is the command via cli to get there?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no native command to delete a Release Bundle V2 using JFrog CLI.

As a workaround, you can use the [Delete Release Bundle v2 Version](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/delete-release-bundle-v2-version) API with the JFrog CLI [Running cUrl](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/examples?tocId=o_wogV8jOEyVeni8AdePGw) option.